# Correct syntax for internal XSL map lookup

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath

I have a internally defined mapping table in an xsl document and I want to access a value using an xpath from an xml as the key. In XSL2 I was led to believe it is easy as this, but I seem to be getting errors.

```
<xsl:variable name="map">
 <entry key="One">testOne</entry>
 <entry key="Two">testTwo</entry>
 <entry key="Three">testThree</entry>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="testVariable">
 <value-of select="$map/entry[@key=A/B]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

If the xml document looks something like:

```
<A>
 <B>Three</B>
<A>
```

testVariable in the xsl document should resolve to 'testThree'

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems here. Firstly it should be **xsl:value-of** and not just **value-of**

Secondly, where you use `A/B` in your xpath condition, this will be relative to the **entry** element you are searching on, not the `A/B` in your original XML.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="key" select="A/B"/>
<xsl:variable name="testVariable">
    <xsl:value-of select="$map/entry[@key=$key]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or better still, write this

```
<xsl:variable name="key" select="A/B"/>
<xsl:variable name="testVariable" select="$map/entry[@key=$key]"/>
```

In fact, you don't have to use the **key** variable at all, just use the **current()** function to get the current context in your XML document

```
<xsl:variable name="testVariable" select="$map/entry[@key=current()/A/B]"/>
```